# Why can't Docker find my sql file to import?

Tags: sql, docker

I have a SQL file I'm trying to import into a local docker instance. I'm running the following command:

```
docker exec -i 868b7935cc37  ../my.file.sql -u {user} --password={password} {dbName}
```

I'm getting the following error back when I run it: 
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"../my.file.sql\": stat ../my.file.sql: no such file or directory": unknown

I'm only one directory away from the file, hence the `../` in the command. I spoke with the person who gave me the file and the username, password and name are all correct. None of the names, passwords, etc. contain any special characters.

I feel like I'm right there. I don't know why I'm getting the `no such file or directory` error.

Any and all help is appreciated!

docker inspect gives me

```
[
{
    "Id": "868b7935cc371a0eef47e84a7ffbddb99b03cfc93e735af31e5b5754680c1f98",
    "Created": "2018-11-15T20:11:44.9362404Z",
    "Path": "docker-entrypoint.sh",
    "Args": [
        "mysqld"
    ],
    "State": {
        "Status": "running",
        "Running": true,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 4819,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2018-11-23T23:15:52.5735445Z",
        "FinishedAt": "2018-11-21T01:52:31.3103165Z"
    },
    "Image": "sha256:583a6e3a3c98793a6c8a3b09d291b574da66f7e1fba6ebfebe3e93c88c3b443a",
    "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/868b7935cc371a0eef47e84a7ffbddb99b03cfc93e735af31e5b5754680c1f98/resolv.conf",
    "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/868b7935cc371a0eef47e84a7ffbddb99b03cfc93e735af31e5b5754680c1f98/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/868b7935cc371a0eef47e84a7ffbddb99b03cfc93e735af31e5b5754680c1f98/hosts",
    "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/868b7935cc371a0eef47e84a7ffbddb99b03cfc93e735af31e5b5754680c1f98/868b7935cc371a0eef47e84a7ffbddb99b03cfc93e735af31e5b5754680c1f98-json.log",
    "Name": "/dmr_mysql_1",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "Driver": "overlay2",
    "Platform": "linux",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "AppArmorProfile": "",
    "ExecIDs": null,
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": [
            "dmr_local_mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql:rw",
            "dmr_local_mysql_data_backups:/backups:rw"
        ],
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "NetworkMode": "dmr_default",
        "PortBindings": {
            "3306/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "3306"
                }
            ]
        },
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
        "AutoRemove": false,
        "VolumeDriver": "",
        "VolumesFrom": [],
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "Dns": [],
        "DnsOptions": [],
        "DnsSearch": [],
        "ExtraHosts": null,
        "GroupAdd": null,
        "IpcMode": "shareable",
        "Cgroup": "",
        "Links": null,
        "OomScoreAdj": 0,
        "PidMode": "",
        "Privileged": false,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "UTSMode": "",
        "UsernsMode": "",
        "ShmSize": 67108864,
        "Runtime": "runc",
        "ConsoleSize": [
            0,
            0
        ],
        "Isolation": "",
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "Memory": 0,
        "NanoCpus": 0,
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
        "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "Devices": null,
        "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
        "DiskQuota": 0,
        "KernelMemory": 0,
        "MemoryReservation": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "MemorySwappiness": null,
        "OomKillDisable": false,
        "PidsLimit": 0,
        "Ulimits": null,
        "CpuCount": 0,
        "CpuPercent": 0,
        "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
        "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
        "MaskedPaths": [
            "/proc/acpi",
            "/proc/kcore",
            "/proc/keys",
            "/proc/latency_stats",
            "/proc/timer_list",
            "/proc/timer_stats",
            "/proc/sched_debug",
            "/proc/scsi",
            "/sys/firmware"
        ],
        "ReadonlyPaths": [
            "/proc/asound",
            "/proc/bus",
            "/proc/fs",
            "/proc/irq",
            "/proc/sys",
            "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
        ]
    },
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Data": {
            "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/830398a5558d1451a520a7219971cfb6f869cfc7aa149373eab77287c2924ee4-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d6fbcced29e35b61a9bb5a8db9cec8c561fdcba5b52a61c62af886de180aa93a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/289d826020070599fe59d4171f40bfcfc41de1bbefa29bcc4cfd0bc0ab5ebb3c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/05572289cc7498d3d29d09d0b9745c0387c56ef06919ef27517c9131a585a895/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/eed1357572b7a67729f776846e8109fa9493e0083d88bb3edeb2c95410bfa2b4/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8163d89b53f562d5476ffc8ccabdcb6a935ee932b2544f0d42ada9650b67eb46/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8ea425a1f09814f6e6f3f9d8f887c0829b2151e359425ea985792a75e65acd90/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ae06aa0cbb069d340970beb76ad8b278ac4b4f97eaceb1f3b36cb4ba15a2128c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/16350f1b36b1eb496286e5ad4cdea02f9931d33a6869a6105da766e40793d81a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/305da8336df57edf64806244981141bd6a05b168653a48f97223e7da0a3ac477/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2265f0da439e923b98007d292dda922f3a90298bb879c07f2f41afa66c971c7b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b5e59e46468f95a1d243b6c99b7421b41715f7ad11bda4095901244a6552bbb9/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/76fdb756320d579aed7713e27b4760a5266fcfde5358903d9e4351d9c77a4b9d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/58952f226dee428fecc6cf23f45e39b4084f10c6214f3ded03ebd87a250318bd/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7f03ca1e222e9ee48d8332e6ec830cb0a2a7a27167d2698847d41d3f18c47bd3/diff",
            "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/830398a5558d1451a520a7219971cfb6f869cfc7aa149373eab77287c2924ee4/merged",
            "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/830398a5558d1451a520a7219971cfb6f869cfc7aa149373eab77287c2924ee4/diff",
            "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/830398a5558d1451a520a7219971cfb6f869cfc7aa149373eab77287c2924ee4/work"
        },
        "Name": "overlay2"
    },
    "Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "volume",
            "Name": "dmr_local_mysql_data_backups",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/dmr_local_mysql_data_backups/_data",
            "Destination": "/backups",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        },
        {
            "Type": "volume",
            "Name": "dmr_local_mysql_data",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/dmr_local_mysql_data/_data",
            "Destination": "/var/lib/mysql",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        }
    ],
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "868b7935cc37",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "3306/tcp": {},
            "33060/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "MYSQL_DATABASE=dmr",
            "MYSQL_USER=dmr",
            "MYSQL_PASSWORD=dmr",
            "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=dmr",
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "GOSU_VERSION=1.7",
            "MYSQL_MAJOR=5.7",
            "MYSQL_VERSION=5.7.24-1debian9"
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "mysqld"
        ],
        "ArgsEscaped": true,
        "Image": "dmr_mysql",
        "Volumes": {
            "/backups": {},
            "/var/lib/mysql": {}
        },
        "WorkingDir": "",
        "Entrypoint": [
            "docker-entrypoint.sh"
        ],
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "ffc27388c47a8468694fe5412bb06e3dda7a7b083d378fba1ab57eace2b3628e",
            "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
            "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "dmr",
            "com.docker.compose.service": "mysql",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.22.0"
        }
    },
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "cbccae535b05d954c1592710bb808814a87bcfbee6617fd1fb0a8f44561faec7",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "3306/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "3306"
                }
            ],
            "33060/tcp": null
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/cbccae535b05",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "",
        "Gateway": "",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "",
        "IPPrefixLen": 0,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "",
        "Networks": {
            "dmr_default": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": [
                    "868b7935cc37",
                    "mysql"
                ],
                "NetworkID": "eaf16cd4854d6bcb607ca7598c5337d42b917164404de82f873b9567ab480df7",
                "EndpointID": "c98e525c7c4f22e5bfb7b6041a2f94fbf81561f518d2a6b550768ef6c32e57d5",
                "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.18.0.2",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "DriverOpts": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

]

Comment: User Pablo Munoz requested that you edit your question to include the output of `docker inspect 868b7935cc37`

Comment: daft question maybe but is your file inside the container or is it one directory up from where you are, outside the container, execing from? If it's inside, how do you know what the container thinks the current directory is? If it's outside, it'll need cp'ing in before a program inside the container can see it. See also https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/#examples

Comment: Please edit your question, remove the backticks around the output you pasted, highlight the entire output and press the {} button above the edit box. The correct way to post multi line code blocks is to prefix every line with 4 spaces (which is what that button does) not surround it with backticks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is a misunderstanding of how docker exec works. If you think of your container as a remote machine, and docker exec as a command you run on your local machine that will cause the remote machine to execute some command installed on the remote machine, it may become more clear

Right now it looks like you have a file on your local machine (outside the container) and you're passing it as the command you wish the remote machine(inside the container) to run, but the file is on your local machine, not the remote so even if it could be processed (docker help page says it must be an executable file- is an sql file executable in this context?) the file isn't on the machine that is going to process it.

Calling docker exec and passing a file reference of a file outside the container, doesn't cause the local file to be sent into the container and executed inside

As such, I think you'll have to do something more like

```
docker cp ../myfile.sql DOCKERCONTAINERNAME:/root/myfile.sql
```

To copy the file into the container and then something like:

```
docker exec DOCKERCONTAINERNAME mysqlimporttool -u mysqluser -p pass /root/myfile.sql
```

To have docker launch the in-container import tool for you and pass the arguments you specified. That tool will start up inside the container, and process the file you copied into the container in the first step

Comment: So the first command works and I can run it with no errors. The 2nd command you gave me is throwing the following error: `OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"mysqlimporttool\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
`

Comment: I've no idea what the name of the executable that will process your file is. You should adjust the second command to be relevant to your setup

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `docker exec` to interact with servers running in containers.  Just use the ordinary client programs you'd normally use to talk to them.

For instance, if you launched the database container, publishing the normal MySQL port, as as

```
docker run -p3306:3306 ... mysql
```

then you could run your script by installing the `mysql` command-line client, and then running

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 ../my.file.sql -u {user} --password={password} {dbName}
```

If you've configured your Docker to require root permission to access it (a very reasonable setup) then this has the additional advantage of not requiring `sudo` just to run it.